# Is posting an incomplete/incorrect answer considered abuse on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, user-accounts, accept-rate, account-suspension

I recently posted this question: [Color picker that sends events per color pick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110139/color-picker-that-sends-events-per-color-pick) and a certain user posted an "answer" which he obviously did not test or compile.

Upon saying that his answer did not compile or even look near right, he attempted to correct it. However, not only did not even compile, it was once again, not even near the right path. After asking him about this in the question, he deleted the response.

Now I know I don't have enough rep here as I am new, but this kind of behavior is just not acceptable. It is very poor behavior on his part and very negatively reflects Stack Overflow. How will I know I will ever get helped when people like him are around? How many of his responses are just spam?

Comment: I don't understand what happened (can't see deleted answer), are you complaining about a user posting a wrong answer? or that he was rude? Or did he just spam something? He's almost 4K, must not be the latest folk in town. By what I understand from your question, he gave a wrong answer, tried to correct it and when still wrong deleted his answer; looks like good behaviour to me

Comment: If an answer isn't correct then don't accept it.

Comment: Its not just the answer was incorrect, it is that he obviously just tried to copy and paste things with out knowing what he was doing, and let obvious syntax errors. Not only that, but when asked about it, he just deleted his response. I am afraid that if this was my first time interacting with him, who know how often he does it? He might be doing this too even more users

Comment: If the answer is poor, you have the option downvote it and leave a comment to explain why you think it's wrong. Pointing the angry finger at a user who might be trying to help as best they can, and particularly calling them out by name, is not constructive behavior.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This behavior seems just fine to me. He attempted to answer your question, but for whatever reason, was unable to do so, so he deleted his answer, as he didn't want to leave a poor answer lying around afterwards.

Ultimately, this is anything but abuse - he's doing exactly what I think anyone should do in a situation like that.

Comment: He didn't even really attempt to answer the question though. He looks like he just opened some doc, saw something that might be slightly relevant and just copy and pasted it. He did nothing to explain the "answer", had syntax errors in it and when asked what something was a something way, he just deleted it.

Comment: Well, sounds like what should be done. Especially, if he had just decided to post a non-answer link-only "answer", and expect you, the question-asker, to go glean it yourself, instead of actually taking the time to write an answer specifically to your question. I think the issue is more with the manner in which he did this - I agree, from what you say, this sounds like sloppy behavior on his part, but nothing that sounds bannable. (Note: Users who provide too many low-quality posts are auto temp-suspended anyway, so no action is necessary on our [or the moderator's] part[s].)

Comment: Ah ok, I wasn't sure what the appropriate action would be for when a user was doing something like he was. If I had the points, or a way to downvote what he did (though he did delete it ...) I would have. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Certainly - personally, I would have downvoted it, especially after the problem wasn't fixed after he specifically edited it to try to do so. After all, the title text for the downvote on answers says it all: `This answer is not useful`.